# Firebase Manage Multiple auth provider

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on android application that uses multiple authentication with the help of firebase like Facebook, Google and Email/Password. Each authentication works well in separate ways.

But, When I am login with google and then signed out and later when i am using facebook to do login by using same Email Id..

It says.

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: An
>   account already exists with the same email address but different
>   sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this
>   email address.

All i want to do is, Merge the account when user try to login with different  authentication provider by using same email id.

Is, there any way to handle this by using firebase.

Please Help.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Comment: But, I think account linking will only works when you are already logged in in system.

Comment: @Priya, I used this logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44528975/3001746

Answer (score 30):

just change it here.. thats all.. you are welcome

[image]

Comment: You get a weird database if you do that.

Comment: Please don't do that. It's a wrong approach. Follow way as prescribed in documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Comment: @RishabhChandel please see Pike's comment to Frank, in his question comment.

Comment: Yes, as the site explains when you click the button... their auth will create multiple auth users for the email address, one for each specific login method.