# Using Facebook Authentication

Tags: facebook, angular, authentication, facebook-authentication

In my Angular2 app I have used the following code:

```
loginfb() {
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
}
```

But the problem is I am getting an error `App Not Set Up: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.`

So I went to Facebook developers, created an app, added the Facebook Login product, went to the product's settings and set the Valid OAuth redirect URIs with the URI given in the firebase console. 
But even then when I am trying to login, I am facing the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you added your app id in the configuration as well?

Comment: @CBroe yes app id and app secret both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes when your app is not live.There are a bunch of possible things which could trigger this error.I am not sure and as you are getting error "**you don't have access to it**",may be you are trying to login through your test version of the Facebook app and you may have not added the user Roles as Testers in Roles section and the you have to add the email address of the Facebook account you are trying to login in setting section.
Then ,make sure that the user you added accepts the request sent before you try to test otherwise it will fail.

And for error "**Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.**"
When you create new app on Facebook, its by default only visible to you and not to public and others won't be able to use it for social login and they will get this error. You may have to go to Go to your Facebook app's dashboard, Select the "Status and Review" tab and set YES or ON.

You can find similar question and answer is there in this link [App Not Set Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085246/app-not-setup-this-app-is-still-in-development-mode).and 
[This app is still in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775198/facebook-api-this-app-is-in-development-mode)

Comment: I made some changes, now the pop up is working and not showing any errors, but after processing the information the pop up is closing and the app is not going to the required page.

Comment: There could be  bunch of possible things like the redirected  URL in not working ,may be allow origin problem like https to http,or your are working behind some firewall which is block the request.Are you getting any error on console?

Comment: I am getting the following error: `Ngcode: "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential"credential: mg {accessToken: "EAAByrZCQryq0BADZATpxuAljsujh8IOOFWiCKpCT9xZA4GGDW…a4exFq6tIZBr3kgRHMV7DGFsXZB4fSDF6kaZAmnX2dl1wZDZD", providerId: "facebook.com"}email: "mail@gmail.com"message: "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address."__proto__: O`

Comment: Issue with Firebase authentication for existing acount check links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917227/firebase-manage-multiple-auth-provider and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459524/handling-linking-accounts-in-firebase.